# Posting multiple questions within a short span of time

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I often think of multiple questions to discuss on Stack Overflow within a short span of time, but I am hesitant to post all of these questions around the same time, since this practice may be frowned upon by the rest of the community (regardless of how useful or relevant the questions may be). Is this type of action permitted?

Comment: For example, I wanted to ask whether it was possible to get the width and height of an image in node.js, and whether it was possible to get the output of a shell command as a string in Javascript.

Comment: As long as you show your code, explain what you tried, what output you got, and what output you expect, you should be fine. Just be sure to show research effort and see the [faq] before posting. Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no issues with that, so long as the questions themselves are of good quality. If they aren't, they may be downvoted and/or closed, but not because they were posted one after another.

Be aware, though, that we have some rate-limiting mechanisms in place:

- users with less than 125 reputation can only post one question every 20 minutes.
- all users can post a maximum of 6 questions per 24 hours.
- all users can post a maximum of 50 questions within a rolling 30-day window.
- you might hit a captcha if you're posting your questions quickly.